# Can someone explain a simple data binding behavior to me C# Silverlight 4.0

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

Here's the scenario:

There is a `XAML` `textbox` bound to a property in the `view model`.

Behavior 1 -

If a value is assigned to a property directly from the code.

1) `SET` is called on the bound property.

2) The property's private field is updated (possibly to `value`, possibly to some other value depending on conditions).

3) `RaisePropertyChange("xx")` is called.

4) `GET` is called.

5) The property is updated in the view. Whatever value was stored in the private field of the property is displayed in the UI.

Behavior 2 -

If a value is assigned to the `property` by a user inputting text into the `textbox`:

1) `SET` is called on the bound`property`.

2) The `properties` private field is updated (possibly to `value`, possibly to some other value depending on conditions).

3) `RaisePropertyChange("xx")` is called.

And that's it. My question is why does step 4 and 5 not happen in scenario 2? `RaisePropertyChange` is being called so shouldn't the `GET` method be called soon after? Can someone explain why it isn't..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scenario 2, the GET call would only happen if that property was bound to more than just the textbox.  Since the textbox is updating it's bound value, there's no need to call a GET, because nothing else is subscribed to it.

Comment: Is there a way to force it? My problem is that once the value is sent to the view model some validation is done on it and in some cases the value originally entered in the textbox will not be the end result of the bound property. In these cases I need GET to be called after SET so that the new value is displayed instead of the bad value passed in by the user that is still sitting in the textbox.

Comment: Interesting...  You might try either firing `RaisePropertyChange` twice (might work), or alternatively, fire an event in the ViewModel that's picked up in the View.  From the view, you could call RaisePropertyChange on the ViewModel, perhaps from an Invoke lambda to ensure that it's picked up as a separate call.  I'd try option 1 first.

Comment: Okay so I am attempting solution 2 (1 didnt work) and the behavior is amazing. If I create a button with a command to the view codebehind with the  code _viewmodel.RaisePropertyChanged(null); and click the button then the properties on the screen are updated. But if I create an event in the SET that is picked up in the view and calls the same code then the UI is not updated. It's like somehow it knows that I'm still in the same line of code from the SET method and disables RaisePropertyChanged() from having any effect on the  UI. How do I invoke from a lambda expression?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought might happen.  My hope is that the Invoke will distinguish it, and force a refresh.  In your view, wrap that RaisePropertyChanged like this: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => _viewmodel.RaisePropertyChanged(null));`

Comment: If THAT doesn't work, the last idea I'd have would be to actually set the property in code again to a null/string.Empty/etc value, and then set it back to the new value.  That could introduce other issues though depending on what exactly you're doing.  Hopefully you don't have to resort to that.

Comment: AHA!! You sir are a genius. That did it. If you were near Atlanta I'd buy you a steak for that. You should see some of the suggestions on my other posts. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

BindingMode will play with what events are triggered.  Sounds link your binding mode is OneWay (the default) and you are expecting TwoWay behavior. Just set it to TwoWay.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

See [Binding Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It is already set to TwoWay, and based on step 5 of scenario 1 I would say that the TwoWay binding is working as expected since the value from the code ends up on the screen.